# Why is intereo not declined like habeo?

Tags: irregular-words

Why is intereo not declined like habeo? I thought all verbs ending in -eo were second conjugation.

However, the 3rd person singular if habeo is habet, but the 3rd person singular of intereo is interit.

What is the explanation?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Intereō is a compound, inter-eō; the second part is the famous irregular verb eō, īre, ivī/iī, itus.

As such, it conjugates like eō does: inter-eō, inter-īs, inter-it, etc.

As for why eō acts like that—the stem was originally something like *ei- (*eiō *eire etc). But Latin generally didn't like sequences of three vowels in a row, so the first singular *eiō became eō; later, *ei became ī, giving a stem of ī- (*eis > īs, *eire > īre, etc) but leaving the first singular with an unexpected e-. Same with the third plural, since that ending also begins with a vowel: *eiont > *eont > eunt.

Comment: (Technically the older form of the infinitive should be *eise, but I'm ignoring rhotacism here since it's not relevant to the vowel discussion.)

Comment: Cf. *iens*, but *euntes, eundum*.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [wiktionary's page](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/intereo#Latin) for the word: it's **īre, eō, īs...eunt...iē̆runt** with an **inter-** stuck to its face. It shares one form with with the ē-conjugation by a pure accident, and in that form *-ō* is the ending and *e-* < *ei-* is the stem (as in **ī**-re < **ei**-re) with no thematic vowel (the *-ē-* of **habē-ō/s/t**... which breaks/shortens if another vowel or final *-t* follows).